# Access JSON file data using preset query - Python

Tags: python, json, variables, key

I am reading a json file with dictionary and values, but I am battling to use a variable as a query item when searching the json file.

```
    x = value_cloud = "%s%s%s" % (["L1_METADATA_FILE"],["IMAGE_ATTRIBUTES"],["CLOUD_COVER"])

    for meta in filelist(dir):
        with open (meta) as data_file: 
            data = json.load(data_file)
        cloud = str(data[x])
```

The error I get is:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "E:\SAMPLE\Sample_Script_AWS\L8_TOA_using_gdal_rasterio.py", line 96, in <module>
    cloud = str(data[x])
    KeyError: "['L1_METADATA_FILE']['IMAGE_ATTRIBUTES']['CLOUD_COVER']"
```

What I actually want is to search the json file for the key in the variable...
The keys do exist in the json file because when I run the following I get the correct output.

```
    cloud = str(data["L1_METADATA_FILE"]["IMAGE_ATTRIBUTES"]["CLOUD_COVER"])
    print cloud
```

My knowledge of python is sketchy, and I am passing the variable through as a string and not an expression or object and therefore it gives me that error. What is the correct way to create the variable and call the keys that I want.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just check - you have given (["L1_METADATA_FILE"],["IMAGE_ATTRIBUTES"],["CLOUD_COVER"]) .. comma separated..

Comment: @HarshaBiyani comma separated is format required for "%s%s%s" % statement...but I know it creates a string and I don't think this is the correct variable type...

Comment: Your key ends up including the brackets in the string, which which is no good.  Can you just use each key in its own variable, like `x, y, z = "L1_METADATA_FILE", "IMAGE_ATTRIBUTES" , "CLOUD_COVER"` and then `cloud = str(data[x][y][z])`?

Comment: @JensHiestermann : yes.. a,b,c = "text1","text2","text3" and str(data[a][b][c])  both are different.

Comment: @coralv thanks for the help! That did the trick.

Comment: Glad to help @JensHiestermann.  I added my comment in as an answer to help close out the question if you wouldn't mind accepting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your key ends up including the brackets in the string, which which where the error comes from.  If you use each key in its own variable, like this:

```
x, y, z = "L1_METADATA_FILE", "IMAGE_ATTRIBUTES" , "CLOUD_COVER"
```

and then:

```
cloud = str(data[x][y][z])
```

it should avoid any errors.